# View Weblogic Logs from Console

Tags: weblogic11g

We deployed an app in a remote weblogic server. They gave us access to the console of the weblogic.
But due to security reasons, we are not allowed to remote connect to the server and view the files.

Question, is there a way from the weblogic console for us to see the logs generated by my application?
I am actually investigating a problem and I think a log from the weblogic can help me see the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can view the Weblogic logs from the console

See the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/ConfigureAndViewLogs.html) on how to do this.

Comment: i know the way you described but is there a way to view log for the console output incase calling a procedure has error in some line on some case. like the netbeans apache output console please?